# How to disable or change the Windows+S hotkey in OneNote

Tags: hotkeys, microsoft-onenote, microsoft-onenote-2010

I've been using some software for a while that uses <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> and I've gotten used to it.  I've just recently started using OneNote 2010 and I find that it's hijacked the <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> hotkey for doing screen clippings. Cool feature, but I'd rather reprogram OneNote to use a different letter. Otherwise I have to reprogram my brain.

I realize I can disable the OneNote system tray icon thing and that'll probably fix the problem, but I'd rather keep the other OneNote hotkeys (<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> and <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>), and wouldn't mind using the screen clipping with <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> or something.

Digging through the options I didn't see any way to change this. Hopefully I'm missing something - otherwise, it's kinda arrogant of a software program to hijack a hotkey like that with no option of configuring it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For OneNote 2007, see [Changing the OneNote Screen Clipping and New Side Note keyboard shortcuts](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/descapa/changing-the-onenote-screen-clipping-and-new-side-note-keyboard-shortcuts). I believe this article will answer your question.

In short, look at this registry key:

```
 HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\12.0\OneNote\Options\Other
```

There are two DWORD values `ScreenClippingShortcutKey` & `NewNoteShortcutKey`. The default values are:

- ScreenClippingShortcutKey: `0x53`
- NewNoteShortcutKey: `0x4e`

If we look in this ASCII table:

[[image: ascii code chart]

Image source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:ASCII_Code_Chart.svg)

In row 5, column 3 (`0x53`), we see the `S`. So, this is where the <kbd>S</kbd> of the hotkey is set.

Change it to another value according to the ASCII table to adjust the hotkey.

Comment: It's a shame they don't appear to have this feature baked in to the program itself.

Comment: Any guess as to where I can find that blessed registry key for Office 2010?

Comment: Windows+N OneNote shortcut actually conflicts with the standard Windows shortcut to open a task from the taskbar (Windows+N+digit). So I would really like to find the way to change this shortcut in Office 2010 (= Office 14).

Comment: In office 14 (whichever version it is) you can add the key to the registry, and it will have the same effect, but will not update the context menu of the icon.

Comment: what about the registry keys for other shortcuts, like Send to onenote (which in office 2013 is defaulted for Windows+N, which I really want to over ride because Windows+N is the only good location on my board)

Comment: This solution stopped working with June 2017 Windows 10 update. I had set Windows+C for screen clipping. This combination is NOT used by Windows OS but still I just stopped working. Anyone with a solution?

Comment: Works in OneNote 2016 on Windows 10 latest as well.

Answer (score 1):

just figured out to disable this..OneNote 2013
Go "File->Options->Display", and uncheck "Place OneNote icon in the notification area of the taskbar"

hth

Comment: Question was how to do this specifically in OneNote 2010 not OneNote 2010.

Answer (score 1):

I have found one better solution, it is for Office 2010.

Open "OneNote"--> File --> Options --> Customize Ribbon

Now, in there, you will find "Screen Clipping" under "Popular Commands". In the "Main Tabs" select "Home" , right click and make new group under it. Rename it.

And then click "Add" and Finally "OK". This is for adding Screen Clipping.

To remove or disable it , search screen clipping under existing group and remove it.

This is my first solution on internet after using lots of free solution over internet for my many problems.

Comment: This worked for me in the OneNote desktop app included in Office 365.

Answer (score 0):

The OneNote icon must be active in the notification area, at the far right of the Windows task bar (bottom right of screen by the clock). I just went to **OneNote** → **Tools** → **Customize**, found the *Screen Clipping* icon and dragged it to the Windows task bar by the clock.