# Change the hotkey in OneNote 2007 (<Windows-N> to <Something-Else > )

Tags: hotkeys, microsoft-onenote-2007

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to disable or change the Windows+S hotkey in OneNote](https://superuser.com/questions/199422/how-to-disable-or-change-the-windowss-hotkey-in-onenote)

OneNote hijacked the <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> key on my System and I can't find a way to tell it to use another hotkey, say <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>

<kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> has been used to start 4Nt ([now TCMD](http://jpsoft.com/)) on my system for ages and I'd like it to stay that way…

Comment: In this case, it is 4NT [violating the Windows specification](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/11/30/6605629.aspx): _[Keyboard shortcuts that involve the WINDOWS key are reserved for use by the operating system.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms646309(VS.85).aspx)_

Comment: @kinokijuf You could argue that OneNote is also in violation, as it's not an OS tool but part of Office

Comment: @GrahamWager Of course, as Raymond pointed out in that blog. It’s just your standard anticompetitive stuff.

Comment: @kinokijuf: Actually 4NT violates nothing ... I'd set the hotkey in Winkey ( https://www.copernic.com/winkey/index.html ) and OneNote overrode it. I suspect Winkey is too old) ... Autohotkey (see Lamb's answer below) however works/cooperates corectly with the OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do this:

1. One way is to kill the **OneNote Launcher**, (it sits in the taskbar and listen to the HotKey) or you can remove it from the running at **Startup**. (Press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> and type `msconfig` and go to Startup tab)
2. Using [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com), you can get back your Hotkey to do anything of your choice by placing the path to the desired program:

   ```
   #n::Run <Path to the executable>
   ```

Comment: Thanks @Lamb, AutoHotkey works .. unlike WinKey it is not overriden by OneNote. I assume WinKey doesn't know/use the latest API.