# How do I disable the OneNote 2013 "Win+Shift+S" hotkey?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys, microsoft-onenote-2013

I use OneNote nearly every day and just upgraded to the (free!) 2013 version. This version registers both the <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> and <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> keyboard combinations. Unfortunately, this conflicts with a custom internal application that registers (and requires)<kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>. I have found [some instructions](https://superuser.com/a/211464/204664) for changing the <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> hotkey, but nothing for the <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> hotkey combination. Is there any way to disable the conflicting shortcut in OneNote?

Comment: You can better change the short cut keys in windows

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that changing the registry entry mentioned in the linked answer also changes the key for the <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> hotkey. That is, changing the "ScreenClippingShortcutKey" value to "5A" changes the mappings to <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> and <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>. Lucky for me!