# How to disable or change OneNote 2016 shortcut

Tags: microsoft-onenote, microsoft-onenote-2016

I would like to disable `ALT+N` shortcut in OneNote 2016. 
`[RIGHT ALT] + [n]` is special character in polish and I am using it often.
I didn't notice this issue in OneNote 2010.

Does anyone know solution to this problem?

Comment: You should be able to just change the [shortcut](http://superuser.com/questions/199422/how-to-disable-or-change-the-windowss-hotkey-in-onenote?rq=1).

Comment: This method doesn't work for me (windows 10 + office 2016)